# Two pointers comparison

Tags: pointers, comparison

```
pf1==pf2    pf1 and pf2 point to the same array element

pf1>pf2     pf1 is the higher address location

pf1<pf2     pf2 is the lower  address location
```

I want to know if the third sentence should be：`pf2 is the higher address location`？

Comment: Which programming language. This is relevant.

Comment: @TheHippo: I can't imagine a situation where this would not be true, assuming pointers are related to addresses in a straightforward way.

Comment: So are you asking if there's a mistake in the third statement? I think there surely is.

Answer (score 0):

The third statement should be either:

- `pf2` is the higher address location
- `pf1` is the lower address location

These statements are equivalent in this context.  The original quote got caught not making its mind up which of the two correct statements it wanted to make and ended up being erroneous by combining them.

Under memory addressing schemes such as the segmented addressing on 8086, it was possible to have two different values for `segment:offset` that actually refer to the same address (because segments overlap).  Depending on whether (or how) the pointer values are normalized before the comparison, you might have `pf1 < pf2` but the pointers still refer to the same address.  However, this is sufficiently esoteric that you're unlikely to ever run into such a problem in practice.